# inserting one account for each row and every dates and payments associated with that account in one row each in (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

**This how the script run from the begin to the  end**

```
INSERT INTO TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2--------- This is working fine 
SELECT  FACS_ACCT_NUM, PROMISE_DATE, PROMISE_AMT, '0'
FROM    MGMT.FACS_PDC_PROMISE 
WHERE   CLIENT_CD IN ('CAP20J', 'CAP20U', 'CAP21E', 'CAP20E', 'CAP21J', 'CAP22E', 'CAP22J', 'CAP22U',
                        'CAP23E', 'CAP23J', 'CAP30E', 'CAP30J', 'CAP30U', 'CAP31E', 'CAP31J', 'CAP31U',
                        'CAP36E', 'CAP36J', 'CAP36U', 'CAP37E', 'CAP37J', 'CAP37U', 'CAP38E', 'CAP38J', 'CAP38U')
AND    PROMISE_DATE >= trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,0),'MM') -- ENTIRE PRIOR MONTHPRIOR MON
AND      (PROMISE_BROKEN_DATE IS NULL or promise_broken_date >=  trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,0),'MM'))
--AND     P.FACS_ACCT_NUM = '17938393'
ORDER BY 1;

COMMIT;

--SELECT * FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2

update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =1
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =2
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =3
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =4
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =5
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

  update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =6
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =7
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =8
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq = 9
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =10
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =11
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;

 update taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2
set dt_seq =12
where (facs_acct_num, pdc_dt_1) in
(select facs_acct_num, min(pdc_dt_1) 
from taiwos.Temp_capone_date_jul2 
where dt_seq = 0 group by facs_acct_num)
and dt_seq = 0;

COMMIT;
```

This script was suppose to insert one  account for each row  and every dates and payments  associated with that  account base on the each sequence from 1- 12  representing each month , Instead the script is inserting one account for each row with the same payments in the entire records\  is not working right .

```
 INSERT INTO TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_PART12 (FACS_ACCT_NUM, PDC_DT_1, PDC_AMT_1, PDC_DT_2, PDC_AMT_2, PDC_DT_3, PDC_AMT_3,
                                    PDC_DT_4, PDC_AMT_4, PDC_DT_5, PDC_AMT_5, PDC_DT_6, PDC_AMT_6, PDC_DT_7, PDC_AMT_7, 
                                    PDC_DT_8, PDC_AMT_8, PDC_DT_9, PDC_AMT_9, PDC_DT_10, PDC_AMT_10, PDC_DT_11, PDC_AMT_11, 
                                    PDC_DT_12, PDC_AMT_12)
SELECT  DISTINCT FACS_ACCT_NUM,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 1 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_1,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 1 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_1,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2 
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 2 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_2,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 2 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_2,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 3 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_3,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 3 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_3,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 4 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_4,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 4 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_4,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 5 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_5,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 5 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_5,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 6 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_6,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2 
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 6 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_6,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 7 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_7,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 7 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_7,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 8 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_8,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2 
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 8 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_8,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 9 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_9,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 9 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_9,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 10 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_10,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 10 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_10,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 11 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_11,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 11 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_11,
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2  
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 12 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_DT_12,
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 12 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum <= 1) PDC_AMT_12
FROM    TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2 
WHERE   DT_SEQ = 1;  

COMMIT;
```

This is  working fine

```
INSERT INTO TAIWOS.CAP_ONE_MONTHLY_WINS
SELECT  A.REF_NO as debt_mgr_rtr_acct_num, D.PNET_ID as pnet_id,
        SUM(case when F.IS_CONTACT >= 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS rpc_cnt,
        SUM(case when F.ACTION_CD IN ('TR','TW','TO') then 1 else 0 end) AS man_atts,
        SUM(case when F.ACTION_CD IN ('DO', 'DR', 'DS', 'DW') then 1 else 0 end) AS auto_atts,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_1,PDC_AMT_1 as pdc_amt_1,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_2, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_2,PDC_AMT_2 as pdc_amt_2,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_3, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_3,PDC_AMT_3 as pdc_amt_3,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_4, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_4,PDC_AMT_4 as pdc_amt_4,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_5, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_5,PDC_AMT_5 as pdc_amt_5,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_6, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_6,PDC_AMT_6 as pdc_amt_6,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_7, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_7,PDC_AMT_7 as pdc_amt_7,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_8, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_8,PDC_AMT_8 as pdc_amt_8,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_9, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_9,PDC_AMT_9 as pdc_amt_9,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_10, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_10,PDC_AMT_10 as pdc_amt_10,
        TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_11, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_11,PDC_AMT_11 as pdc_amt_11,TO_CHAR(PDC_DT_12, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as pdc_dt_12,PDC_AMT_12 as pdc_amt_12,
        TO_CHAR(A.ACCT_PLACE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS plcmt_strt_dt
FROM  MGMT.FACS_ACCT_EVAL A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MGMT.FACS_ACTION_RESULTS F
    ON F.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD = A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD AND F.ACCT_NUM = A.ACCT_NUM
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MISRPT.DEF_DU_ARROW_FINANCIALS M
      ON M.SOURCE_SYS_CD = A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD AND M.ACCOUNT_NUM = A.ACCT_NUM
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_PART1 T
        ON T.FACS_ACCT_NUM = A.ACCT_NUM
         LEFT OUTER JOIN MISRPT.DEF_DU_CAP_SUPPL_PHONE D
          ON A.ACCT_NUM = D.ACCOUNT_NUM AND A.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CD = D.SOURCE_SYS_CD
WHERE   M.HARD_RECALL_DTE is null
AND     A.CLIENT_NO IN ('CAP20J', 'CAP20U', 'CAP21E', 'CAP20E', 'CAP21J', 'CAP22E', 'CAP22J', 'CAP22U',
                        'CAP23E', 'CAP23J', 'CAP30E', 'CAP30J', 'CAP30U', 'CAP31E', 'CAP31J', 'CAP31U',
                        'CAP36E', 'CAP36J', 'CAP36U', 'CAP37E', 'CAP37J', 'CAP37U', 'CAP38E', 'CAP38J', 'CAP38U')
GROUP BY A.REF_NO, D.PNET_ID,
        PDC_DT_1,PDC_AMT_1,PDC_DT_2,PDC_AMT_2,
        PDC_DT_3,PDC_AMT_3,PDC_DT_4,PDC_AMT_4,
        PDC_DT_5,PDC_AMT_5,PDC_DT_6,PDC_AMT_6,
        PDC_DT_7,PDC_AMT_7,PDC_DT_8,PDC_AMT_8,
        PDC_DT_9,PDC_AMT_9,PDC_DT_10,PDC_AMT_10,
        PDC_DT_11,PDC_AMT_11,PDC_DT_12,PDC_AMT_12,
        TO_CHAR(A.ACCT_PLACE_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This question isn't getting answered because, I suspect, people find the amount of code daunting - I know I do.  Can you not reduce it to a simpler example that still illustrates your problem?

Comment: +1: Need a more simple statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a procedure with a cursor to hold your insert statement and a record to hold your cursor. Then scroll through the record to update your records matching your criteria.

cursor t1_cur is  SELECT  DISTINCT FACS_ACCT_NUM, 
        (SELECT PDC_DT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2   
         WHERE DT_SEQ = 1 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM and rownum = x) PDC_DT_x, 
        (SELECT PDC_AMT_1 FROM TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_DATE_JUL2
...
 type t1_type is table of t1_cur%ROWTYPE;
In execution
...
           -- insert an initial row
           INSERT INTO TAIWOS.TEMP_CAPONE_PART12 (FACS
...
open t1_cur;
 loop
      fetch t1 bulk collect into my_rec1 limit 200000;
      for i in 1 .. my_rec1.count loop
          if  rec1(i).DT_SEQ = 1 AND FACS_ACCT_NUM = FACS_ACCT_NUM\
          update foo set bar
          ...
          elsif
          ...
          elsif
          ...
          else
...
```